# How to check if a given Amazon S3 key exists from shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3

I would like to check given s3 key exists from shell script.

```
S3 Path:
========
s3://Bucket/test/names/12345/names-ca/one.txt
s3://Bucket/test/names/12346/names-ec/two.txt
```

I would like to check s3://Bucket/test/names/12345 is exists or not.what could be better approach to check this one from shell.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the awscli to test for the presence of an object in S3. For example:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket mybucket --key dogs/snoopy.png
```

You will get a JSON response and a zero returncode if the object exists (and you have permission to issue HeadObject against it).

Here's an example bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3api head-object --bucket mybucket --key dogs/snoopy.png 1>/dev/null 2>&1

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "S3 object exists"
else
    echo "S3 object does not exist"
fi
```

To test if there are objects under a given S3 prefix such as `dogs/`, you can issue:

```
aws s3 ls mybucket/dogs/ --recursive | grep -v "\/$" | wc -l
```

The output will be the count of S3 objects, for example 0 or 2. You can capture this in the normal way, for example:

```
COUNT=$(aws s3 ls mybucket/dogs/ --recursive | grep -v "\/$" | wc -l | tr -d ' ')

if [[ $COUNT -eq "0" ]]; then
    echo "No objects under dogs/"
else
    echo "Some ($COUNT) objects under dogs/"
fi
```

If using an AWS credentials profile other than your default, append `--profile myprofile` to the awscli command.

Comment: I just wanted to check till seq number (s3://Bucket/test/names/12345)

Comment: Mis-read your original question, apologies. Have added a potential solution for that. In your case the prefix would be `test/names/12345/` (not `test/names/12345` because that would capture a file named `test/names/12345.png`).